# Windows no longer detects my camera. Why?

Tags: windows-7, hdmi

I've got a handheld camera connected to our Windows 7 computer. It used to work.

We unhooked the tower to move it and changed that plan and left it where it is.

Once we reconnected everything, the HDMI cable is no longer detected by the TV.
Nothing was changed!

How can we get them talking again?